# Forcing focus to the desktop using VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net

How can I, in VB.NET, force the focus to the desktop?

Comment: This is NOT a duplicate of [3374312 forcing-focus-for-desktop-applications-built-in-net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3374312/forcing-focus-for-desktop-applications-built-in-net)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean.  Do you want to remove focus from all open windows or minimize all windows (Show desktop)?

You can show desktop using P/Invoke:

```
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)
Private Const KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = &H2
Private Const VK_LWIN = &H5B


''' <summary>
''' Shows the desktop by minimizing all windows
''' </summary>
Public Sub ShowDesktop()
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, 0, 0)
    keybd_event(77, 0, 0, 0)
    keybd_event(VK_LWIN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0)
End Sub
```

[source](http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet2109.htm)